# Laser mouse moves cursor while in the air

Tags: windows, mouse, input-device, input

If I lift my mouse a few cm from the desk and I move it the cursor still responds. Only when the mouse is lifted more than +- 5cm does the cursor stop to respond.

This is not desired behavior I guess. I want the cursor to only respond if the mouse is in contact with a surface. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: As the comments are indicating, this IS desired behavior.  This mouse is too sensitive.  Try a cheaper one.  I'm curious why you're picking it up that much in the first place?

Comment: I use very low sensitivity when gaming, I pick up the mouse very often. This moving in the air causes confusion, unexpected behavior.

Comment: Just curious, what mouse do you use? I've used Razor, Logitech and Microsoft laser mice and never had them be *that* responsive. However, it still stands that your mouse is working as desired in my opinion.

Comment: Sharkoon FireGlider (3600 dpi). Really great value. This is my only complaint.

Comment: if you are picking up the mouse because you've run out of room on your desk to move it in a particular direction you might want to consider increasing the mouse speed in windows and/or increasing the sensitivity in the games you play. this way you can move the cursor further on screen with less actual movement of the mouse

Comment: alternatively you might try an optical thumb ball mouse

Comment: I know your pain. I bought today new mouse and it's also this way. And incr. of mouse speed is not a solution cause in ffp you need to have precision (low speed) and speed movement (big distance) and you end up moving mouse up and away. So this is not desired when cursor moves when mouse is in the air. Still searching a solution. Nothing interesting here.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this means that your mouse actually functions *very well*. You could use a surface that doesn't reflect a laser as well, **which would be something with a darker color** (absorbing some of the light, rather than reflecting it), if you really don't like this, but I don't think there is physically a way to turn the laser power down, so to speak.

Comment: That or a sheet of glass or similar surface (plexi?) which allows the beam to pass through it and not reflect it back so much.

Comment: my mousepad is black but I still had this problem pretty badly. What worked great for me: Put a piece of clear scotch tape over the laser on the bottom of the mouse.